# Installing problems with JDK 11 (please have a look)

Tags: java, installation, java-home, java-11

What exactly do I have to do to install JDK 11? In which directory do I have to install Java and what exactly have to be the value of JAVA_HOME (if necessary?)? I'm using Eclipse for programming and it forces me to install JDK in its subfolder "jre" (at all versions (WEB, PHP, Java, etc.)), so I did so, but shouldn't it actually work to just install JDK 11 normally, in the default directory (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1)?...

My OS ist Windows 10.

Before someone asks: Yes, I searched for an answer, but it didn't work (and/or I didn't understand completely)...
([How to use jdk without jre in Java 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52584888/how-to-use-jdk-without-jre-in-java-11/))

Comment: Can you please [edit] to add more details on what issues you were facing when you tried the solutions in that post?

Answer (score 0):

The precise method will depend on your operating system e.g. Linux uses rpm/deb/snap while Windows uses exe/msi installers. If you want to manage multiple JDK versions and are on Mac OSX, Linux, Cygwin, Solaris and FreeBSD you can use [SDKMan](https://sdkman.io/):

```
$ sdk install java
Downloading: java 11.0.1-open
In progress...
################################################################################################################# 100.0%
Repackaging Java 11.0.1-open...
Done repackaging...
Installing: java 11.0.1-open
Done installing!
Do you want java 11.0.1-open to be set as default? (Y/n): Y
Setting java 11.0.1-open as default.

$ java -version
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13, mixed mode)
```

As part of the installation it will update `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` to point to the selected Java version.