# Install JRE (but not JDK) via brew on macOS

Tags: java, homebrew

How do I install only JRE (not JDK) using homebrew on macOS?

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: can explain your question in details? because you can't develop java programs only with JRE
You will need JDK for compiling your programs.JRE provides only runtime environment,but JDK is something you will need to compile your code to make them executable by your JRE.You will need javac for compiling your code which is present in JDK.

Comment: @CodeF0x I know, that `brew cask install java` installs the JDK and on Ubuntu it's `sudo apt install default-jre` (This does install JDK, doesn't it? Although it's named `default-jre`). What I tried is searching the internet for JRE and brew

Comment: @HarshShah What details do you need? I simply do not want to install the whole JDK

Comment: If you want to install Java 11, then there is no separate JRE anymore. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52584888/how-to-use-jdk-without-jre-in-java-11

Comment: @WimDeblauwe This question became a "Popular Question" (1k views). Maybe you want to add your comment as an answer, which I would accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to install Java 11, there is no separate JRE anymore. See [How to use jdk without jre in Java 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52584888/how-to-use-jdk-without-jre-in-java-11)