# jre folder not found for java se 13

Tags: java

I downloaded the installer for the java se 13 development kit. When the installation completed the jre folder was missing in the C://java directory. When I entered the command **java -version** in the cmd prompt I got three errors stating:

**error:** opening registry key 'software/javasoft/jre'

**error:** could not find java.dll

**error:** could not find java se runtime environment

How to rectify this situation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use jdk without jre in Java 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52584888/how-to-use-jdk-without-jre-in-java-11)

Comment: Find all Java.exe's and run the one you need directly. `dir c:\java.exe /s` and then `c:\whicheverpath\java.exe`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you remove any java.exe, javaw.exe and javaws.exe from your Windows\System32 folder and if you have an x64 system (Win 7 64 bits) also do the same under Windows\SysWOW64.

[Java Error opening registry key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362037/java-error-opening-registry-key)

Have a look.